# Ionic: Item with title and detail text

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

**Question**: Seems too simple - how can I achieve an item with title text and detail text?

**Example**:
[image]

**Note**: I have tried two possible solutions. Both result in a blank white item without content.

```
<ion-item-sliding>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="pin" item-start color="primary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Title </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input disabled="true" [(ngModel)]="event.detail"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-sliding>
```

and

```
  <ion-item-sliding>
      <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="pin" item-start color="primary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-grid>
         <ion-row>
          <ion-column>
            <ion-label>Title</ion-label>
          </ion-column>
          <ion-column>
            <ion-input disabled="true" [(ngModel)]="event.detail"></ion-input>
          </ion-column>
        </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-sliding>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Thumbnail List` item (**[docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#thumbnail-list)**):

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <ion-icon name="pin" item-start color="primary"></ion-icon>
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p text-wrap>{{ event.detail }}</p>
  </ion-item>
```